# Two fields with foreign key from a table - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make the fields user_id and following_id have reference table of User ID field. I've tried everything, have searched the internet and still can not.

Migration:

```
    class CreateFollowers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :followers do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :following, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Models:

```
class Follower < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :following, :class_name => 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follower1_as_user, :class_name => 'Follower', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  has_many :follower2_as_user, :class_name => 'Follower', :foreign_key => 'following_id'
end
```

I even read the documentation and I look at the code always I think I'm right.

Comment: Can you explain more about "have reference table of User ID field"? AFAICS your migrations for user references is correct. Your following_id will assume there is a "followings" table (because you haven't told it that the class it's meant to be is a user). Also: tell us why you know it's not currently working? How do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reference` method does not support foreign keys to tables where the table name does not match the reference name.

A solution could be to build the same with less Rails magic:

```
def change
  create_table :followers do |t|
    t.references :user,         index: true, foreign_key: true
    t.integer    :following_id, index: true
    t.timestamps null: false
  end
  add_foreign_key :followers, :users, column: :following_id
end
```

Furthermore the association declaration in your `Follower` model needs to know about the non obvious column name too:

```
class Follower < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :following, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'following_id'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is on your design of models and tables. You have a user (1) that follows another user (2). So, 1 is a follower, 2 is a followeed.

What if 2 also decides to follow 1?

You will have a table like this:

Relationships

id / follower_id / followeed(or following)_id

1   /     1_id   /   2_id

2   /     2_id   /   1_id

You need for that a has_many through reversible relationship. Is quite a complex app for a beginner. Luckily, there is the perfect book guide that should take you some days. Take a look at [Michael's Hartl guide](https://www.railstutorial.org/book)

All you need is there.